# Reference for this theorem: $a, b$ coprime, $f(k) := ka \bmod b$, then $f$ is bijection on $\lbrace 0, …, b−1 \rbrace$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

I need to use the following theorem in a paper but have to expect that some of the audience (physicists) is not familiar with it, so I would like to reference it:

> Let $a$ and $b$ be two coprime integers.
>   Let $f(k) := ka \bmod b$.
>   Then $$k≠j ⇒ f(k) ≠ f(j) \quad ∀ k,j ∈ \left\lbrace 0, …, b-1 \right\rbrace$$
>   or with other words: $f$ is a bijection on $\left\lbrace 0, …, b-1 \right\rbrace$.

What is the name of this theorem and if it does not have one, what is a sligthly more general theorem to reference instead? If even this does not exist, I am interested in a citable reference for this.

I have gone through Wikipedia’s lists of theorems and lemmas and checked everything named by less than two persons and did not find anything. I also checked a few books on number theory and did not find this statement.

Note that I am not looking for a proof (I can do that myself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proposition 2.1.13 from *Elementary Number Theory: Primes, Congruences, and Secrets* by William Stein (freely available [on his site](http://wstein.org/ent/)) is:

> If $\text{gcd}(a,n) = 1$, then the equation $ax ≡ b
> ~(\text{mod } n)$ has a solution, and that solution is unique modulo $n$.

From there, it is only a small step to the required statement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has a name, but it follows from this fact:

> If $X$ is finite then $f: X \to X$ is a bijection iff it is an injection iff it is a surjection.

You could also phrase the specific instance of that fact as follows:

> Since $a$ is a unit mod $b$, the map $k \mapsto ka$ is a bijection.

If you want to get down to the details, you could say that $f$ is injective because

> If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $b$ divides $ac$, then $b$ divides $c$.

This is an extension of [Euclid's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma) and, like it, follows from [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezout%27s_identity).

Comment: My question is about the statement that $f$ is a injection in the first place. I wouldn’t have used the term *bijection* at all, weren’t it for the readability of the title.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, $f$ is an injection because it is a surjection and that follows from the fact that $1$ is in the image, since $a$ is a unit.

Comment: That’s all quite nice if you know about rings, unit, etc. But then you probably also know the statement in question anyway and I would not need to reference it.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, I gave it another go. See my edited answer.

Comment: I am afraid, there is still far too large a step from your extension of Euclid’s lemma to the statement in question, if you know next to nothing about number theory and similar.